# Drupal Ubercart not populating Anonymous User cart with items

Tags: ubercart

I have a site that the cart works fine for logged in users but won't populate with items for Anonymous users. When you click "Add to Cart" it shows an empty cart.

My problem can be seen at:
 usscmc.org then in the featured articles click on John Kretchmer
Click on "Click Here" to buy tickets then on "Add to cart"

I've watched the tutorials and checked all that I could find to check. My Anonymous Checkout is on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It appears that the server is sending a delete session cookie request after adding to cart. No session cookie = no cart data. You need to find out what's killing the session.

Comment: Try checking your "users" table in the database and see if the anonymous user uid is SET to 0, if not then make it 0 .